# PHPBrew Compile Error PHP 5.4.31 with apxs2

Tags: php, linux, compiler-errors, ubuntu-14.04

I'm trying to compile PHP with apxs2 support using PHPBrew. MY PHP version is 5.4.31. The following command compiles properly

```
phpbrew install 5.4.31 +default +gd +json
```

But the following command gives an error

```
phpbrew install 5.4.31 +default +gd +json +apxs2=/usr/bin/apxs2
```

I am getting the following error

> home/samer/.phpbrew/build/php-5.4.31/ext/standard/browscap.c:401:
>   undefined reference to 'php_pcre_exec' ext/pcre/php_pcre.o: In
>   function 'zm_info_pcre':
>   /home/samer/.phpbrew/build/php-5.4.31/ext/pcre/php_pcre.c:128:
>   undefined reference to 'php_pcre_version' ext/pcre/php_pcre.o: In
>   function 'zm_startup_pcre':
>   /home/samer/.phpbrew/build/php-5.4.31/ext/pcre/php_pcre.c:154:
>   undefined reference to 'php_pcre_version' ext/pcre/php_pcre.o: In
>   function 'make_subpats_table':
>   /home/samer/.phpbrew/build/php-5.4.31/ext/pcre/php_pcre.c:193:
>   undefined reference to 'php_pcre_fullinfo'
>   /home/samer/.phpbrew/build/php-5.4.31/ext/pcre/php_pcre.c:202:
>   undefined reference to 'php_pcre_fullinfo'
>   /home/samer/.phpbrew/build/php-5.4.31/ext/pcre/php_pcre.c:203:
>   undefined reference to 'php_pcre_fullinfo' ext/pcre/php_pcre.o: In
>   function 'pcre_get_compiled_regex_cache':
>   /home/samer/.phpbrew/build/php-5.4.31/ext/pcre/php_pcre.c:267:
>   undefined reference to 'php_pcre_fullinfo'
>   /home/samer/.phpbrew/build/php-5.4.31/ext/pcre/php_pcre.c:399:
>   undefined reference to 'php_pcre_compile'
>   /home/samer/.phpbrew/build/php-5.4.31/ext/pcre/php_pcre.c:395:
>   undefined reference to 'php_pcre_maketables'
>   /home/samer/.phpbrew/build/php-5.4.31/ext/pcre/php_pcre.c:417:
>   undefined reference to 'php_pcre_study' ext/pcre/php_pcre.o: In
>   function 'php_pcre_match_impl':
>   /home/samer/.phpbrew/build/php-5.4.31/ext/pcre/php_pcre.c:624:
>   undefined reference to 'php_pcre_fullinfo'
>   /home/samer/.phpbrew/build/php-5.4.31/ext/pcre/php_pcre.c:659:
>   undefined reference to 'php_pcre_exec'
>   /home/samer/.phpbrew/build/php-5.4.31/ext/pcre/php_pcre.c:678:
>   undefined reference to 'php_pcre_get_substring_list'
>   /home/samer/.phpbrew/build/php-5.4.31/ext/pcre/php_pcre.c:749:
>   undefined reference to 'php_pcre_free' ext/pcre/php_pcre.o: In
>   function 'php_pcre_replace_impl':
>   /home/samer/.phpbrew/build/php-5.4.31/ext/pcre/php_pcre.c:1056:
>   undefined reference to 'php_pcre_fullinfo'
>   /home/samer/.phpbrew/build/php-5.4.31/ext/pcre/php_pcre.c:1087:
>   undefined reference to 'php_pcre_exec' ext/pcre/php_pcre.o: In
>   function 'php_pcre_split_impl':
>   /home/samer/.phpbrew/build/php-5.4.31/ext/pcre/php_pcre.c:1520:
>   undefined reference to 'php_pcre_fullinfo'
>   /home/samer/.phpbrew/build/php-5.4.31/ext/pcre/php_pcre.c:1536:
>   undefined reference to 'php_pcre_exec'
>   /home/samer/.phpbrew/build/php-5.4.31/ext/pcre/php_pcre.c:1600:
>   undefined reference to 'php_pcre_exec' ext/pcre/php_pcre.o: In
>   function 'php_pcre_grep_impl':
>   /home/samer/.phpbrew/build/php-5.4.31/ext/pcre/php_pcre.c:1784:
>   undefined reference to 'php_pcre_fullinfo'
>   /home/samer/.phpbrew/build/php-5.4.31/ext/pcre/php_pcre.c:1808:
>   undefined reference to 'php_pcre_exec'
>   ext/fileinfo/libmagic/softmagic.o: In function 'check_fmt':
>   /home/samer/.phpbrew/build/php-5.4.31/ext/fileinfo/libmagic/softmagic.c:357:
>   undefined reference to 'php_pcre_exec' ext/filter/logical_filters.o:
>   In function 'php_filter_validate_regexp':
>   /home/samer/.phpbrew/build/php-5.4.31/ext/filter/logical_filters.c:439:
>   undefined reference to 'php_pcre_exec' ext/filter/logical_filters.o:
>   In function 'php_filter_validate_email':
>   /home/samer/.phpbrew/build/php-5.4.31/ext/filter/logical_filters.c:547:
>   undefined reference to 'php_pcre_exec' ext/readline/readline.o: In
>   function 'zif_readline_info':
>   /home/samer/.phpbrew/build/php-5.4.31/ext/readline/readline.c:278:
>   undefined reference to 'rl_mark'
>   /home/samer/.phpbrew/build/php-5.4.31/ext/readline/readline.c:251:
>   undefined reference to 'rl_mark'
>   /home/samer/.phpbrew/build/php-5.4.31/ext/readline/readline.c:253:
>   undefined reference to 'rl_pending_input'
>   /home/samer/.phpbrew/build/php-5.4.31/ext/readline/readline.c:287:
>   undefined reference to 'rl_pending_input'
>   /home/samer/.phpbrew/build/php-5.4.31/ext/readline/readline.c:290:
>   undefined reference to 'rl_pending_input' ext/readline/readline.o: In
>   function 'zif_readline_list_history':
>   /home/samer/.phpbrew/build/php-5.4.31/ext/readline/readline.c:371:
>   undefined reference to 'history_list' ext/spl/spl_iterators.o: In
>   function 'zim_spl_RegexIterator_accept':
>   /home/samer/.phpbrew/build/php-5.4.31/ext/spl/spl_iterators.c:2022:
>   undefined reference to 'php_pcre_exec' ext/zip/php_zip.o: In function
>   'php_zip_pcre':
>   /home/samer/.phpbrew/build/php-5.4.31/ext/zip/php_zip.c:708: undefined
>   reference to 'php_pcre_exec' collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit
>   status make: *** [sapi/cli/php] Error 1

How do I solve this? I've installed all dependencies as mentioned on PHPBrew requirements page and this isn't working.

Comment: have you tried not to specify path for apxs2 ?

Comment: What version of Apache? Does /usr/bin/apxs2 exists?

Comment: What is the OS? Does libpcre3-dev installed in system?